# How to encode a String to Byte[]

Tags: java, string, hex, decode

I have a string that contains hex numbers
But i want to decode them to text and convert them to a string

If my the string is "FF505000010000000A00015634"
They are in hex, how do i make them to \xFF \x50... and so on

Please help me here

Comment: ur question is not clear.

Comment: Give a input/output example. You can get rid of the spaces with `str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");`

Comment: Can you provide a real text as hex string because FF505000010000000A00015634 is nothing like ASCII text encoded as hex.

Comment: I believe he has text encoded as hex, and want to convert it back to text. Despite the title is about the inverse process...

Comment: I changed the question a little, hope it is clearer this round

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    String s = "FF505000010000000A00015634";
    s = s.replaceAll(" +", "");
    byte[] bytes =  new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray();
```

Comment: netbeans is telling me to create a class for BigInteger?

Comment: I am not sure about netbeans, but java.math.BigInteger belongs to Java SE since version 1.0

Comment: oops, forget about import. Thanks, i'm going to test

Comment: but be warned about negative numbers, or better, numbers starting with a byte greater than \x7F: Using the above code `bytes[0]` will be `\x00` and `bytes[1]` will be `\xFF`!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to turn a text as hex string into text is to use BigInteger.

```
String s = "Hello world!";
String hex = new BigInteger(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)).toString(16);

hex = hex.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // remove any whitespaces.
String s2 = new String(new BigInteger(hex, 16).toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.printf("\"%s\" as hex is %s, converted back is \"%s\"%n", s, hex, s2);
```

prints

"Hello world!" as hex is 48656c6c6f20776f726c6421, converted back is "Hello world!"

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You basically get every two character, and parses it to an `int`, which can also be interpreted as a `char`. From that, you build another decoded `String`.

```
String s = "FF505000010000000A00015634";
if (s.length() % 2 != 0) {
    //odd amount, so wrong string. Throw exception.
}
String decoded = "";
int j = 0;
while (j < s.length()) {
    String sub = s.substring(j, j + 2);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(sub, 16);
    decoded += (char)i;
    j += 2;
}
System.out.println(decoded);
```

My output was quite random, but I figure your teststring wasn't all that good.

For `Hello world!`, use this:

```
String s = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21";
s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

So what actually happens:

1. Every two characters should be interpreted as one characters.
2. So cut the `String` in pieces of two characters.
3. Convert every two hex characters to an actual `int` value, making it possible to make the actual conversion.
4. Append every from hex to ASCII decoded character to your new decoded `String`.
5. Repeat until you've had all characters in the hex `String`.